# How does List(1,2,3) work in Scala?

Tags: list, scala

How does this work in Scala?

```
val something = List(1,2,3)
```

`List` is abstract, and you can't construct it by invoking `new List()`, but `List(1,2,3)` works just fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`List(1,2,3)` is "magic syntax" to call the `apply` method in the [companion object](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596155957/AdvancedObjectOrientedProgramming.html#CompanionObjects) of trait or class `List`.

Answer (score 16):

Because it is a call to the `apply` method of the list companion object. In scala, a method called *apply* can be called with the method name ommitted (i.e. just with parens). It is by this mechanism that sequence and Map access works

Hence, `List(1, 2, 3)` is in fact:

```
List.apply(1, 2, 3)
```

So this is then a call to the apply method of List's [*companion object*](http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2009/09/companion-object.html), the [implementation of which](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List%24) is:

```
override def apply[A](xs: A*): List[A] = xs.toList
```

So you can see that `apply` is a method which takes a repeating parameter (a *sequence*), and calls the `toList` method on this sequence. This *toList* on *Seq* is inherited from `TraversableOnce`:

```
def toList: List[A] = new ListBuffer[A] ++= seq toList
```

So you can see that this creates a list via a `ListBuffer` and the `++=` method:

```
override def ++=(xs: TraversableOnce[A]): this.type =
  if (xs eq this) ++= (this take size) else super.++=(xs)
```

This ultimately gets its implementation of `++=` from `Growable`:

```
def ++=(xs: TraversableOnce[A]): this.type = { xs.seq foreach += ; this }
```

Invoking `new List()` does not work because List is a `trait` (and a `sealed` one at that) - you would have had to apply implementations for the abstract methods. The fact that it is sealed means that it can only be *implemented* by a class in the same source file.

Comment: I can construct list by invoking List() but not by invoking new List()

Comment: @Shaman - apologies, I didn't see the "new" lurking in there. Answer amended